# Multipeer connectivity over Bluetooth?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I started to advertise, started to browse.
When **on the same WiFi, it works**.

But when I turn WiFi off, and **leaving only Bluetooth**, nor even the `-(void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser*) browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID*) peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary*) info` gets called.

Do I have to **indicate to advertise on Bluetooth explicitly somehow**? Or should it work this way seamlessly?

With GameKit there was a setting for this. I can't find any similar in MC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***same code*** will work.

No need to explicitly advertise on Bluetooth. It will automatically come. Just take care of keeping bluetooth of both devices ON.

There is no explicit setting for bluetooth or Wifi, It will connect devices in whatever possible way they are available.

Comment: I hope so. Gonna keep trying.

Comment: I dint get...what you are saying

Comment: Is there a way to say that I want the Multipeer Connectivity only to use Bluetooth Connection in it is a IPv6 network ??

Comment: @SamkitJain Can you help my question If you have any experience in that field: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164362/working-with-multipeerconnectivity-in-ios-swift

Answer (score 2):

Oh, **it was `discoveryInfo`**. I was included it just before trying the setup over Bluetooth.

But as it turned out, this `discoveryInfo` dictionary have plenty of exceptional rules. See [`initWithPeer:discoveryInfo:serviceType:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser/initWithPeer%3adiscoveryInfo%3aserviceType%3a)

```
// This won't work without a single line of warnings or errors (!).
info = @{ @"myID" : @(102) };

// This will work.
info = @{ @"myID" : @"102" };
```

Comment: The docs clearly state keys and values need to be strings.  Of course, an error would be nice :)