# MultipeerConnectivity - MCNearbyServiceBrowser constantly finding disconnected peers

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, multipeer-connectivity

I´m working with **MultipeerConnectivity** Apple framework. Connection, advertiser and browser seems to work very well until now but I notice that when any session connects a peer and then it disconnects for any reason my `MCNearbyServiceBrowser` still finding that peer even if it doesn´t exist anymore. Obviously `MCSession` reports a **not connected** status with the peer.

Does anyone have an idea of why this is happening?

I have override the dealloc method in my mc handler class like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self.session disconnect];
    
    self.peerId = nil;
    
    self.session    = nil;
    self.browser    = nil;
    self.advertiser = nil;
    
    self.session.delegate    = nil;
    self.browser.delegate    = nil;
    self.advertiser.delegate = nil;
}
```

And I also have a tear down method:

```
- (void)teardownService
{
    [self.session disconnect];
    
    self.session    = nil;
    self.advertiser = nil;
    self.browser    = nil;
    
    self.session.delegate    = nil;
    self.browser.delegate    = nil;
    self.advertiser.delegate = nil;
}
```

This issue happen with all the devices.

Comment: Take a look at the answer I gave here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26289811/disable-wifi-from-multi-peer-connectivity

Comment: Thanks! I found a helpful post at the Apple Dev Forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a really helpful answer at the Apple Dev Forums.

Here the [link](https://devforums.apple.com/message/956736#956736).

Basically what resolved this issue was recycling the `MCPeerID`. When the object is created I serialize it and stored in `NSUserDefaults`. And anytime I need it back, like when I tear down the service and start it again I go to the stored object and used it instead of creating a new one.

You can find the next example code in the attached link above:

```
- (MCPeerID *)peerID {
    if (!_peerID) {
        _peerID = [MyClassName getRecycledPeerID];
    }
    return _peerID;
}

+ (MCPeerID *)getRecycledPeerID
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    // if peer id exists, use that; else create one
    if ([defaults objectForKey:kRECYCLED_PEER_ID]) {
        NSData *peerIDData = [defaults dataForKey:kRECYCLED_PEER_ID];
        return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:peerIDData];
    }
    else {
        return [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:[UIDevice currentDevice].name];
    }
}
```