# Multipeer Connectivity: peers fail to connect sometimes

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I'm working on a game that uses MPC. I got it working, but I find that connecting (especially more than 2 peers) often fails. Peers start connecting (MCSessionState.Connecting), and then they just don't (MCSessionState.NotConnected). Other times, it just works like a charm.

Is this just a problem with the framework, or is there something I could be doing wrong?

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/chat-app-swift-tutorial/). In my implementation, one of the players is the browser, and the rest are advertisers. The only workaround I've come up with is to try to connect again if it gets the .NotConnected flag, but sometimes it will try to reconnect 3 or 4 times before it succeeds (takes way too long).

Here's the relevant code:

MPCManager (this class is MCSessionDelegate, MCNearbyServiceBrowserDelegate, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiserDelegate)

```
func advertiser(advertiser: MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser, didReceiveInvitationFromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, withContext context: NSData?, invitationHandler: (Bool, MCSession) -> Void) {
    self.invitationHandler = invitationHandler

    delegate?.invitationWasReceived(peerID.displayName)
}

// MARK: MCSessionDelegate method implementation


func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
    switch state{
    case MCSessionState.Connected:
        print("Connected to session: \(session)")
        connectedPeers.append(peerID)
        delegate?.connectedWithPeer(peerID)

    case MCSessionState.Connecting:
        print("Connecting to session: \(session)")

    default:
        delegate?.disconnectedFromPeer(peerID)
        print("Did not connect to session: \(session)")
    }
}
```

The delegate class:

```
func invitationWasReceived(fromPeer: String) {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        self.appDelegate.cManager!.invitationHandler(true, self.appDelegate.cManager!.session)
        self.connectingLabel.text = "Connecting"                
    })
}


func connectedWithPeer(peerID: MCPeerID) {
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        self.connectingLabel.text = "Connected to \(peerID.displayName)"
        if self.appDelegate.cManager!.connectedPeers.count == self.appDelegate.cManager!.foundPeers.count {

        //game setup if all peers are connected
        //stop browsing and advertising
       }
    })
}

func disconnectedFromPeer(peerID: MCPeerID) {
    print("disconnected setup")
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        self.connectingLabel.text = "Couldn't connect to \(peerID.displayName)\n\nRetrying"
        if self.isBrowser {
            self.appDelegate.cManager!.browser.invitePeer(peerID, toSession: self.appDelegate.cManager!.session, withContext: nil, timeout: 20)
        } 
    })


}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, however I am using the MCAdvertiserAssistant and MCBrowserViewController classes for the connection. Users are finding each other, but I always get the NotConnected in the session didChangeState function.

   func session(session: MCSession, peer peerID: MCPeerID, didChangeState state: MCSessionState) {
        if (state == MCSessionState.Connected) {
            self.view.window?.rootViewController!.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

Comment: @EndreOlah I did some testing, and if I turn Bluetooth off, and only use wifi, thing work much better, but I've seen some posts on SO where people say the opposite is true.

Comment: My issue was solved by implementing the    

func session(session: MCSession, didReceiveCertificate certificate: [AnyObject]?, fromPeer peerID: MCPeerID, certificateHandler: (Bool) -> Void) {
        certificateHandler(true)
    }

Earlier it was just place holder func, without the certificateHandler(true) line and it was not allowing the phones to connect.

Comment: Thanks, @EndreOlah, but that didn't change much for me. It seems like it gets all messed up when you have both wifi and bluetooth active, but gets better when only using one at a time.

Answer (score 5):

#### Implement this delegate method

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session didReceiveCertificate:(NSArray *)certificate fromPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID certificateHandler:(void (^)(BOOL accept))certificateHandler
{
     if (certificateHandler != nil)
     {
         certificateHandler(YES);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.

Comment: It's the same code already mentioned in one of the comments. I tried it, but didn't seem to make a lot of difference. Thanks, though.

Comment: Have you create same peerID instances for the  MCSession, MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceBrowser? And used it instead of creating them as local variables (let localPeerID = ...). @coopersita

Comment: Yes, I even went as far as serialzing and recycling the peerID as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26594740/multipeerconnectivity-mcnearbyservicebrowser-constantly-finding-disconnected-p