# Working with MultipeerConnectivity in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, multipeer-connectivity

I'm working with [MultipeerConnectivity framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/multipeerconnectivity) in iOS, followed a nice [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/) and it worked well.

I have one question, I have two devices with wifi turned OFF but Bluetooth is ON, for the above approach to work, is it necessary for the two devices to be paired(via bluetooth, manually by the user in iOS settings)?

Will it work even if the devices are not paired manually?

If yes, do I need any special code setup or the above code will just work?(I have tried, for me It didn't work. Might be the OS issues? [source1](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/62247), [source2](https://openradar.appspot.com/27243227))

If no, Is it possible to do Bluetooth pairing automatically via a program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do *not* need for the devices to be paired.

The code I used in my [Multipeer Connectivity tutorial](https://gist.github.com/RF-Nelson/8a3e6319b0607cf6b181ae4ee00f6c4c) required no pairing. This code allowed one iOS device to act as a remote control for another iOS device's camera and send the photos back to the original device using Bluetooth or WiFi. The app works over Bluetooth without any pairing between the two devices.

Hope this helps!

**UPDATE**

MPC will not work over Bluetooth on iOS 11+

Comment: To verify this approach works, you can [download the app from the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/open-source-selfie-stick/id1084487132?mt=8)

Comment: Hi Nelson, I was going through with the tutorial. I have few doubt.. Both the devices should be iOS device? I want to connect my iPhone to non iOS camera over Wifi and Control for photo and video.

Comment: @Er.Maheshwari In order to use the Multipeer Connectivity Framework, the devices have to be iOS devices.

Comment: Starting iOS11, peer-to-peer networking [no longer works](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/263873#263873) over Bluetooth. So Multi-Peer-Connectivity will not work over Bluetooth on iOS 11+.

Comment: @R.F.Nelson. I want my devices connect automatically and start reliable session without using MCBrowserViewController how this can be done any help will appreciate.